# How to bind multiple eventhandlers for hoverIntent?

Tags: jquery, binding, event-handling, mouseover, hoverintent

I have the following code in one of my js files

```
$('#elementID').hoverIntent({
    over: function() {//function#1 body},
    out: function() {// function#2 body}
});
```

and in another one of my js files I want to add another method to hoverIntent.
But the new binding overwrites the previous one and only the new one will execute.

```
$('#elementID').hoverIntent({
    over: function() {//function#3 body}
});
```

so I want both function#1 and function#3 to be executed on hover.

is that even possible with hoverIntent?

if not would you please point me in another direction so I can do that?

NOTE: I don't have permission to change the first file. I just want to add extra functionality to the hover.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to modify the plugin `hoverIntent` so that it's configuration variable, `cfg`, is public. After line `cfg = $.extend(cfg, g ? { over: f, out: g } : f );` in the plugin, add:

```
cfg = $.extend(cfg, g ? { over: f, out: g } : f );
$.fn.hoverIntent.cfg = cfg;
```

Then, you can do this:

```
$("#elementID").hoverIntent({
    over:   function(){ $(this).val("over"); },
    out:    function(){ $(this).val("out"); }
});

var cfg = $("#elementID").hoverIntent.cfg;
$.extend(cfg, { over: function(){ $(this).val("new over"); } });
$("#elementID").hoverIntent(cfg);
```

It's not ideal, but I'm not sure of another way to do this without modifying the plugin, extending the configuration variable, and re-initializing `#elementID`.

**UPDATE 1:**

I previously misunderstood OP's request. He needed the function#1 and #3 but not #2 to fire:

```
$("#elementID").hoverIntent({
    over:   function(){ //function #1 },
    out:    function(){ //function #2 }
});

var cfg = $("#elementID").hoverIntent.cfg;
var oldOver = cfg.over; // function #1

$.extend(cfg, { 
    out: false,
    over: function(){
    oldOver(); // call oldOver aka function #1 above
    // function #3
}});
$("#elementID").hoverIntent(cfg);
```

**UPDATE 2:**

My solution of above does not work because it merely creates a global variable for `cfg` which is then modified by any additional usage of `$.hoverIntent`.

Here is another stab at it using the `$.data()` method instead:

After line `cfg = $.extend(cfg, g ? { over: f, out: g } : f );` in the plugin, add:

```
cfg = $.extend(cfg, g ? { over: f, out: g } : f );
$(this).data('cfg', cfg);
```

Then:

```
$("#elementID").hoverIntent({
    over:   function(){ //function #1 },
    out:    function(){ //function #2 }
});

var cfg = $("#elementID").data('cfg');
var oldOver = cfg.over; // function #1

$.extend(cfg, { 
    out: false,
    over: function(){
    oldOver(); // call oldOver aka function #1 above
    // function #3
}});
$("#elementID").hoverIntent(cfg);
```

Comment: I don't really know why, But it seems that the cfg is not available.
I even tried just setting the oldOver it won't work.
$.extend(cfg, { over: function(){oldOver();}});
nothing happens and the popup won't show anymore.

I changed the sensitivity so I can track down see if it is getting the cfg correctly. but when debugging I got a different sensitivity (=7) at all times for  $("#elementID").hoverIntent.cfg.

Comment: Did you modify the plugin's code as I indicated above? You have to set `cfg` to be publicly accessible.

Comment: Object { sensitivity=7, interval=200, timeout=200}.     this is the cfg I'm getting for that element all the time. with two over and out functions.

Comment: Where in the plugin did you add `$.fn.hoverIntent.cfg = cfg;`?

Comment: after this line:
cfg = $.extend(cfg, g ? { over: f, out: g } : f );

Comment: I have lots of hoverIntents in the page. it might be returning the cfg of the last hoverIntent that has been executed.
could this be causing the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's the issue. After looking over the code for `hoverIntent`, it would need to be refactored to provide a public `cfg` that is local to each element it is being called on.

Comment: dgilland, I really appreciate the help here.
But something is still wrong. the second over function is working perfect. but the problem is with $(this) in the oldOver. it's not pointing to the element anymore. this is what I get from firebug when the oldOver triggers. $(this) :  [Window application.do] - fyi the name of my project is application. which should be [a#elementID]

Comment: You'll have modify `oldOver()` so that it accepts a jQuery obj as one of its arguments. Then you can pass in `$('#elementID')`. So `function oldOver($obj){ $obj.foo(); }`, then `oldOver($('elementID'));`

Comment: My friend, YOU ARE THE BEST :) . Thank you so much for all the help.it's finally done.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but it came up on search, so I'm plugging my answer here in case anyone else runs across it.

The hoverIntent plugin isn't meant to handle multiple callbacks, so I've patched a version that is. It's not fully tested for cross-browser compatibility, but since everything's done through jQuery's APIs it should be okay.

[Github link](https://github.com/jfmatt/hover-intent-multiple)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the hoverIntent plugin isn't set up to support multiple event handlers.  You'll probably have to patch the hoverIntent code to make this work.