# Adding different timeout's to jQuery scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, hoverintent

i have a litte problem...

i created a litte script (for jQuery HoverIntent-Plugin)

the script is showing my submenu for **7 seconds**

( **WORKS PERFECT** )

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".navi-item").hoverIntent({
            over: showSub,
            timeout: 7000,
            out: hideSub
            });
        });
    function showSub(){ $(this).find('>ul').fadeIn(100); }
    function hideSub(){ $(this).find('>ul').fadeOut(100); }
</script>
```

now i created another script (for jQuery HoverIntent-Plugin)

the script is adding a class for **3 seconds** if a specifi class isn't set

( **WORKS ONLY WHEN I DISABLE THE CODE ABOVE** )

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".navi-item").hoverIntent({    
                timeout: 3000,  
                over:function(){
                    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
                        $(this).addClass("active2");
                    }
                },
                out: function(){
                    $(this).removeClass("active2");
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

now i tried to combine both codes

( **WORKS.. but only with 1 timeout** )

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".navi-item").hoverIntent({    
                timeout: 7000,  
                over:function(){
                    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
                        $(this).addClass("active2"); // ADDCLASS
                    }
                    $(this).find('>ul').fadeIn(100); // SUBMENU
                },
                out: function(){
                    $(this).removeClass("active2"); // ADDCLASS
                    $(this).find('>ul').fadeOut(100); // SUBMENU
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

is there a way to keep running script 1 and 2 at the same time?

**OR**

is it possible to set different timeouts from hoverintent to **//ADDCLASS** and **//SUBMENU**

regards berni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: [Github link to my version of the plugin, for anyone who finds this in the future.](https://github.com/jfmatt/hover-intent-multiple) It's not particularly well optimized, so don't overdo it, but it works.

Looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519076/how-to-bind-multiple-eventhandlers-for-hoverintent). Basically, the answer is "you can't" - hoverintent was coded in such a way that any event handler you add is going to overwrite the older one. That thread's answerer takes a couple of stabs at patching hoverintent to add the functionality you're looking for, but it doesn't look like he's managed it yet.

I'm going to try my hand at writing a new version of the plugin; give me a few minutes, and I'll either discover that it's more of a pain than I thought or post a Github link.

Comment: It is in fact a bit of a pain, because all of the timeout information is bound directly to the object via closures, and in order to do what you want I need to bind them instead to the configuration object and save it in jQuery's data cache, then make sure to call each one. I've made some progress, but I need to go to class now - I'll try to get this finished up tomorrow morning.

Comment: Took another quick look at it, and it turns out I was doing more work than I needed to. [Here you go.](https://github.com/jfmatt/hover-intent-multiple) If it works for you, please mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: i will try it out :D but can only use script 1 and 2 right? or is it possible to add timeouts to script 3?

Comment: You have a couple options. Either use my code and add your two actions separately, or use either mine or the original and add you own timeout. If everything is the same except the timeout function and when you call it, just add

    setTimeout(function() {$(this).find('>ul').fadeOut(100); }, xxx);

to the out function, where xxx is the difference in delays between the first and second effects.

Comment: i have the following problem.. i tried it first with code 1+2 and added "hoverIntentMultiple" to both scripts. when i hover over an link with submenu popsout and stands for 7 seconds. but when for example 1 second is over and i move the mouse to the next link the ADDCLASS doesn't work.. and the submenu doesn't close after 7 seconds. i have to move the mouse again back over the submenu link, then move to side and wait 7 seconds. the popup is closing and then i can move to the next link. and this is working.. any ideas?

Comment: Yep, you're right. There was a bug that was letting the elements share data rather than each having their own state, which led to some screwiness when you moved the mouse straight from one to the other - I just neglected to do that in testing, apparently. Looks to be all better now.

Comment: the updated version works perfect!! thank you... maybe you can edit your answer and insert the link to the script :D